# "In the preceding paragraph" vs "in the last paragraph"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms, phrase-meaning, academia

I am writing an academic paper.

After finishing paragraph A, I want to refer to A in paragraph B, which follows A.
I am confused with choosing "in the preceding paragraph" or "in the last paragraph".
Both of them seem fine.
Do these two phrases only differ in popularity? I think "in the preceding paragraph" is used
more widely.
Or "in the preceding paragraph" is more formal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Just say *preceding* and stop worrying about it.

Comment: *Preceding* is perhaps a little more formal. Using *last* you run the slight risk of the reader thinking you're referring to the *final* paragraph of the paper, though paragraph B would make your meaning perfectly clear by using the past tense: "In the last paragraph it *was shown* that. . ."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thanks for your excellent suggestion!

Comment: I would use "previous" or "preceding."